# Using the digits $2$, $3$, $4$, $5$ and $6$, find the sum of all $5$-digit numbers that can be formed such that no two digits are same?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

Using the digits $2$, $3$, $4$, $5$ and $6$, find the sum of all $5$-digit numbers that can be formed such that no two digits are same?

Why each of the number would be in any place $4!$ times and not $5!$ times?

And how to find the sum? Please can someone explain. There are many questions based on this concept. But I am not able to understand how to find sum of all the $5$-digit numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's another way . . .

There are$\;5! = 120\;$such numbers.

For each such number $n$, pair it with what I'll call its complement:$\;88888-n$

Thus, there are$\;5!/2 = 60\;$such pairs.

It follows that the sum is just $60\times 88888 = 5333280$.

Comment: I did not understand after 120 numbers step @quasi

Comment: For example, pair the number $32645$ with $56243$. Note that they sum to exactly $88888$. You can do this with all the qualifying numbers. So the idea is to group them in pairs. Since each pair adds to $88888$, you can just multiply $88888$ by the number of pairs.

Comment: But why are we making a pair? And why 88888-n?

Comment: Because then we can add repeated sums by multiplication.

Comment: Each of the digits $2,3,4,5,6$ has a "complementary" digit which adds to $8$. If you take one of the qualifying numbers, $n$ say, and replace each digit by its complement, the new number is $88888-n$. For example, using $n=32645$, we get $88888-n=88888-32645=56243$.

Comment: I want to know why there are 4! ways. And not 5! ways. Why are we fixing the digits? @quasi

Comment: I'm showing an alternate way of finding the sum. I'm not doing it by fixing one digit at a time, so $4!$ plays no role in my version.

Comment: I understood your way of solving it also. But wanted to know this method also :) @quasi

Comment: Parcly Taxel's answer explains the $4!$ count. For example, consider the numbers with the digit $3$ in the left-most position. The remaining $4$ digits $(2,4,5,6)$ can be ordered in any way, so $4!$ ways.

Comment: but why are we fixing the digit? @quasi

Comment: In my version, I'm not fixing anything.

Comment: The idea of fixing digits is to count how many times a given digit occurs in a given position. So we can add the contributions from each position more easily. By symmetry, since there are $120$ numbers and $5$ distinct digits, then for any given position, there should be an equal number of each of the digits occurring in that position. Hence the count for each position, each digit is $120/5=24$, or equivalently $5!/5=4!$.

Answer (score 1):

Fix one digit in any place. Then, using the remaining digits, it is clear that $4!$ and not $5!$ numbers can be formed; there are $5!$ 5-digit numbers to sum up *in total*.

To get the final sum, consider the sum of the digits in the units place first: $4!(2+3+4+5+6)=24\cdot20=480$. This would be multiplied by $10^n$ for the $10^n$ place, so the sum is $480\cdot11111=5333280$.

Comment: Why are we fixing the digit? @ParcyTaxel

Comment: @SakuziMarkel To show that each individual digit occurs only $4!$ times in any _given_ place in the 5 digits.

Comment: but normally individual digit occurs 5! times. What is the use of fixing it @ParclyTaxel

Comment: @SakuziMarkel It occurs $5!$ times in the entire sum, $4!$ times in each "fixed" place.

Comment: did not understand. I am trying to. It's tough @ParclyTaxel

Answer (score 0):

As an example, how many times does the number $2$ appear in the last position? Or how many numbers can we make of the form $\#\#\#\#2$?

Well we have four positions to fill in with $3$, $4$ ,$5$ and $6$. That's just the same as asking how many four digit numbers are there with those digits? $4!$ is the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to look at it.  As noted elsewhere, there are 120 different numbers.  Since each place (1s, 10s, 100s, etc.) holds 2, 3, 4, 5, and 6 the exact same number of times, the average for each place is $120 \times 44444 = 5333280$.